# How to model a time dependant matrix with RNN?

Tags: matrix, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on video classification. So let's say, I sub-sample the video temporally. So for each sub-sample, I engineer some features out of it. Let's say I can represent these features with a two dimensional matrix.

So, these values of the matrix are time-Dependant. So for each video, I have a set of matrices, which are time dependent.

So I need to use a RNN to model these time dependent matrix values and represent the video. This representation should classify the video in to classes. In other words, the RNN should be able to classify the video in to classes, depending on these time dependent matrix values.

I need to know, Is this possible with RNNs? would it be a good practice? If so, what are the guide lines anyone could provide me. What is a good library to use? What would be good tutorials? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You flatten the images of the video and use them as an element of the sequence.

You will have to put a convnet under the RNN, most likely, to get reasonable results.

As such, you feed the image to a convnet, then flatten the activation map and feed it to the RNN cell.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36992625/447599